# Unable to install Ubuntu as well as Windows 10

Tags: 16.04

I had windows 10 installed on my Laptop (HP ac122tu) and I wanted to install Ubuntu 16.04.1 on my Laptop so I deleted my C:/ Drive (i.e. where Windows 10 was installed) and tried to install Ubuntu on my Laptop but it gives Warning of

> This machines's firmware has started this installer in UEFI mode but
>   it looks like there maybe existing operating systems already installed
>   using BIOS compatibility mode, If you continue to install Debian in
>   UEFI mode,it might be difficult to reboot into any BIOS-mode operating
>   system.

then I continued with that and the installation started but at end of the installation it gives error of GRUB Installation failed

```
The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into / target/. without the GRUB boot loader, the system will not boot.
```

So then I retried to Installed Windows 10 but I am unable because windows 10 cannot be installed on a dynamic disk.

Please Help? I dont want to loose the data of other drives.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this with many computers, it is not the grub install that actually fails but the update-grub that makes the first config file that fails. the problem is that the if/then statement in 30_uefi-firmware errors.

the easiest fix is after it error, choose the command line prompt at the bottom of the installer menu. and use nano to edit the file /target/etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware. I have changed mine to read:

```
gettext_printf "Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration\n" >&2
cat << EOF
  menuentry 'uefi-firmware' {
  fwsetup
  }
EOF
```

after editing rerun install grub. note: on some systems the print command needs to be commented out temporarily for the installer

Comment: please can you explain more I am new to Linux

Comment: what do you need more explanation on?

Comment: Windows has made one partition for all drive and left 500 mb only now I cannot Install

Comment: remove the windows partition, like you did the first time.